# Gridview DataFormatingString is not working for some columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have grid , in that grid four columns are having "Data Formatting" attribute. Two columns are giving result according to "Data Formatting". But two columns are not taking the condition mention in "Data Formatting". Here we mention decimal two places value format in "Data Formatting" attribute for four columns.

Here is aspx code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" 
       AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView2_PageIndexChanging"
        OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" CssClass="Grid">
               <RowStyle CssClass="GridRow"/>
                 <Columns>
                     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="No" DataField="id" Visible="false"/>
                     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Scenario" DataField="Scenario"/>
                     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Type" DataField="Type"/>
                     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Station Name" DataField="StationName"/>
                     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Action" DataField="Action"/>
                     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="minH" DataField="minH" 
                       SortExpression="minH" DataFormatString="{0:F2}"/>
                     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="maxH" DataField="maxH" 
                       SortExpression="maxH" DataFormatString="{0:F2}"/>
                     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Min Level" DataField="Min_OL" 
                       SortExpression="Min_OL" DataFormatString="{0:F2}" />
                     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Max Level" DataField="Max_OL" 
                       SortExpression="Max_OL" DataFormatString="{0:F2}" />
                </Columns>
                     <PagerStyle BackColor="White" Height="40px" Font-Bold="true" Font-
                       Size="Medium" ForeColor="Green" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                     <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" 
                       Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="3" />
                     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#ABDB78" ForeColor="Black" Height="35px" Font-
                       Size="13px" Font-Names="verdana"/>
                </asp:GridView>
```

I am also putting here code behind functions:

```
                 protected void PumpGridBind()
                 {
                  string name = Request.QueryString[1].ToString();
                  string query = "select q1.ID  ,  q1.Scenario, q1.Type,  
                  q1.StationName ,q1.MinH, q1.MaxH ,q1.Station_Id, q1.Min_OL, q1.Max_OL,
                  q2.Daily_Abstraction as Action from (select  
                   SD.id,SD.Scenario,PR.Type,PR.StationName,max(if(PARAM = 'minH', Value, ' 
                  -999.00')) as 'minH',max(if(PARAM = 'maxH', Value, ' -999.00')) 
                  as 'maxH',psd.Station_Id,psd.Min_OL,psd.Max_OL from sgwebdb.param_reference as 
                  PR Inner join sgwebdb.scenario_data as SD ON PR.Param_Id = SD.Param_Id INNER 
                  JOIN sgwebdb.qualicision_detail as Q ON SD.SCENARIO = Q.Alternative INNER JOIN
                  sgwebdb.pump_station_detail as psd ON psd.Station_Id = PR.Station_Id where  
                  PR.Type = 'Pump' and Q.Alternative = '" + name + "' GROUP BY PR.Id) q1 JOIN 
                  (SELECT t1.Daily_Abstraction ,t1.Station_id  FROM sgwebdb.pump_station_data t1
                  INNER JOIN (SELECT Station_id, MAX(lastupdate) as lastupdate FROM 
                  sgwebdb.pump_station_data  GROUP BY Station_id ) t2 ON t1.Station_id = 
                  t2.Station_id AND t1.lastupdate = t2.lastupdate) q2 on 
                  q1.Station_Id=q2.Station_Id";

        this.GridView2.DataSource = PSI.DataAccess.Database.DatabaseManager.GetConnection
        ().GetData(query);
        GridView2.DataBind();

    }

    protected void GridView2_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView2.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        PumpGridBind();
    }
```

RowDataBound Function :

```
    protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
              if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
           {
              string iText = e.Row.Cells[5].Text;
              if (iText == "-999.00")
              {
                e.Row.Cells[5].Text = "-999.00";
              }

              else
              {
                double num = Convert.ToDouble(iText);
                string jText = e.Row.Cells[7].Text;
                double min = Convert.ToDouble(jText);
                string kText = e.Row.Cells[8].Text;
                double max = Convert.ToDouble(kText);


                if (num >= min && num < max)
                {
                    //e.Row.Cells[5].CssClass = "GridCond2";
                    e.Row.Cells[5].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
                }

                else if (num >= max)
                {
                    //e.Row.Cells[5].CssClass = "GridCond1";
                    e.Row.Cells[5].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                }

                else
                {
                    //e.Row.Cells[5].CssClass = "GridCond3";
                    e.Row.Cells[5].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

                }
            }
         }
       }
```

for "minH" and "maxH" , it is not showing decimal two places value but "Min_OL" and "Max_OL" are showing decimal two places values.
I tried DataFormatString="{0:0.00}" but that one is also not working.

Comment: have you checked that input you are providing in case of minH(maxH) and Min_OL(Max_OL) is same.?(decimal in each case)

Comment: @AshokRathod in both cases datatypes are Double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the source of your data - in case it is a database, ensure that SQL type is including decimals (force it by multiplying with 1.0). If other source, check the same.

You can check the type of data coming through using the following as a Template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="minH DataType">
  <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("minH").GetType()%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: in your code  <%#Eval("minH").GetType()%>
is giving error

Comment: it is saying that "code blocks are not supported in this context"

Comment: no it is not working in itemtemplet as well.same error is there.

Comment: Are you putting the above code in the <columns> section of the Gridview? Please check for spelling mistakes...

Comment: I cannot see why it won't work... As a sample, we have the below code which works with no problem.`<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="350px" HeaderText="Setting">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="padding:8px">
                                <b><%#Eval("Title")%></b><br />
                                <span class="smallgray"><%#Eval("Description")%></span>                            
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>`

Comment: I put it in asp label and its working now.and it is saying datatype is System.String

Comment: do you know how to handle these string values for displaying as a two decimal number?

Comment: If your datatype is string, then your source is sending the data as string. If you can't change the source, then try to convert it to decimal first this way: `Format(CDec(MyStringValue), "0.00")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61040/discussion-between-vim-and-navigator).

Answer (score 0):

please try simple {0:F}  Instead of  {0:F2}. and also check that data format in all four values is same.

Comment: bro I tried {0:F} also but same result is there and datatypes are Double for all four columns

Comment: In that case please verify your column names are proper and you are not getting any exception during your execution.verify that in your data source proper columns are exist and they are with the same name

Comment: There is no error , I get that grid but only thing is that two columns Min_OL and Max_OL are showing decimal two places value but other two minH and maxH are showing more than two places after decimal.I just edited the question and put that code behind function.please check